# sqlcmd: reconciling -W and -Y

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

I have an automated batch process that uses sqlcmd to pull data from a database and dump it into a text file. Many fields in that database are of type `varchar(max)`, Sqlcmd limits these fields to 256 characters unless I add something like `-y 0` to the flags in the sqlcmd call.

This gives me the full text for fields larger than 256 characters, but it also adds a great deal of whitespace; the fields are padded to make each field as big as it could possibly be according to its data type, essentially giving me huge files with lots of padding and wasted space.

I could fix this by adding `-W` to my sqlcmd flags, but this gives me an error saying that `-W` and `-y` are incompatible.

Has anyone had this problem before? Thoughts on how to solve it?

Comment: Do you *have* to use SQLCmd or could you use the bulk copy features of SSIS (depending on the version of your SQL Server)?

Comment: I have to use sqlcmd. Boss says so.

Comment: I would try very hard to convince your boss that SSIS is much better for this sort of task - it is what it was designed for, and is really easy to use from SSMS.

Comment: Like Oracle sqlplus, Microsoft sqlcmd should not be considered to be a data extraction tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this thread](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/996720-osql-formatting.html) there is the suggestion that specifying the column separator using `-s` can trim the data as if it is not specified the data comes out fixed width.

If that does not work have you tried `RTRIM(LTRIM(ColumnName))` in your `SELECT` query?

Comment: @SuperNES - Then I'm out of ideas, I have to admit I use SSIS more than SqlCmd, sorry.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Trust me, I have already had a number of animated conversations about the... appropriateness... of sqlcmd for this sort of thing.

Comment: I think you should either post process the large files to remove the padding or show this Stack Overflow question to your boss as a reason to move to SSIS, as I do not think you will get SqlCmd to do exactly what you want.

Comment: I'd disagree with the suitability argument - for small amounts of data sqlcmd is quick and simple and should be the right tool for the job. Yes, I know that the total amount of extra space padding is small in these cases, but globally it all adds up - think about how much the extra load wastes in power when all the small inefficiencies are added up, all over the world. This seems yet another example of Microsoft's gross, basic ineptitude and lack of attention to detail. /rant haha

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue while creating a CSV file with SQLCMD and got it solved by tricking SQLCMD. Instead of returning several fields and let SQLCMD put the comma as separator, I just concatenate all the fields putting the commas myself in it. I know it's an ugly workaround, but that solved my problem. Hope it can help someone else.

Comment: Why the downvote? The accepted answer wouldn't even solve the issue, at least I'm showing a way to get it solved without proposing the client to use a different tool. Besides, I don't remember why, but I could not use RTRIM(LTRIM()) as a solution.